# pythonnet clr is not recognized in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, .net, interop, clr, python.net

I have installed pythonnet to use clr package for a specific API, which only works with clr in python. Although in my python script (using command or regular .py files) it works without any issues, in jupyter notebook, `import clr` gives this error, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clr'`. Any idea how to address this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple suggestion: compare `sys.path` in both cases and see the differences. Your ipython kernel in jupyter is probably searching in different directories than in normal python process.

Answer (score 0):

since you are intended to use clr in jupyter, in jupyter cell, you could also 
`!pip install pythonnet` for the first time and every later time if the vm is frequently nuked